# opengraph meta data not working properly for LinkedIn regardless of Post Inspector

Tags: share-open-graph

There seems to be something odd in OG metadata in our website and I can't figure out what it is...

For example this page: https://en.ilmatieteenlaitos.fi/wind-energy.

Has og:image and og:title (there is some extra stuff, but they shouldn't matter)
`<meta data-n-head="ssr" data-hid="og:image" property="og:image" content="https://images.ctfassets.net/hli0qi7fbbos/7aa7VLl18PM8amWiILgeCH/30be16653881211492963375de425d7b/Tuulivoimalat_Hamina_ilta_SariHartonen.jpg"> <meta data-n-head="ssr" data-hid="og:title" property="og:title" content="Wind energy - Finnish Meteorological Institute">`

Previews show correctly in here: https://www.opengraph.xyz/url/https%3A%2F%2Fen.ilmatieteenlaitos.fi%2Fwind-energy/

Post Inspector shows preview incorrectly just like sharing the page in Linkedin app: https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fen.ilmatieteenlaitos.fi%2Fwind-energy. Using inspector should refresh the cache, but it's not doing it.

I tested with a test page (https://cdn.fmi.fi/demos/stackoverflow/some) in different domain with same header and all worked just fine with inspector and app and everything.

Is the problem deeper in en.ilmatieteenlaitos.fi -settings since all worked fine in cdn.fmi.fi?

edit: did more testing on our beta-site so content of the page is same as in production. All worked just fine in beta-site. So my guess there is something wrong in production website's settings which is out of my comprehension. Any tips? :) We are using Contentful and AWS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is `oq:url`. Currently it's always set to our website's mainpage. Maybe Linkedin caches stuff based on that so all shares get the same cached result. This is not the case for twitter. Not sure about other some-platforms.

I also added `prefix="og: https://ogp.me/ns#` to html-element's attributes. Not sure how much difference this makes.

Now Linkedin shares seem to work in our preproduction site which uses same data as production.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this meta tags debugger tool here: https://thumbsmith.com/validator

My guess would be that maybe you need to add width / height tags for LinkedIn to pick it up

Comment: I tried the link you provided. Yes, image dimensions are missing, but it should break the whole preview card? Preview card in Linkedin is missing title etc in sharing the website as well as in Linkedin's post inspector...